# How to refresh NetSuite sandbox code (only) from production?

Tags: version-control, netsuite, suitescript

**Refresh NetSuite sandbox from production (code only)**

I realize that we can refresh out sandbox from production but we don't want to refresh the entire sandbox, instead we want to refresh NetSuite SuiteScript, NetSuite Forms & UI Objects.

**NetSuite's proprietary infrastructure/code and challenge it brings**

I resisted asking this question for several weeks thinking it was too basic but it doesn't appear that way. After working with NetSuite for a while it has become clear that the line between source code and data has become blurry and it's my opinion this is exactly what makes refreshing code challenging.

I've also learned that storing NetSuite code in version control software is next to impossible (for all code) and this leads me to believe that my desire to refresh code only might be impossible as well. I have to wonder how IT shops that are encumbered by SOX compliance issues are able to satisfy auditors when it comes to controlling and modifying the business logic.

**The real question and reason for refreshing the sandbox code**

My motivation for refreshing sandbox code is the fact that we are encountering unexpected behavior in our sandbox accounts with certain forms (invoice & estimate) where custom tax fields (Ava-Tax) mysteriously moved from the items tab to a tab that contains transaction body fields! The form appears to not have been updated by anyone in over a year and there were no packages installed in the sandbox that might have broken the form.

If I cannot refresh source code is there a way to determine how a NetSuite form became corrupted knowing that the NetSuite Form is stored in a proprietary way and with no apparent source code available? I understand most of the NetSuite code is JavaScript that runs on both the server and client and there are parts that are unavailable to anyone outside of NetSuite.

Any solutions or suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not at all impossible to store NetSuite code in Source Control. We use git to track all of our NetSuite source, and we follow a process similar to gitflow. Our `master` branch is always kept in sync with Production. Anytime we push code to Production, that gets merged from its feature/fix branch up to `master` and tagged as a release. If we want to roll back, we just revert `master` back a commit and upload the whole project to the File Cabinet. Then, if we want to refresh a Sandbox to match Production, we simply checkout `master` and upload all of that to the Sandbox.

Sandboxes themselves are much more difficult to keep in sync with a single branch in source because we are constantly developing there on separate feature branches.

If you do not already have such a system in place, all you really need to do is download the zip of your SuiteScripts folder from the Production File Cabinet and upload that to your Sandbox.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, confirms what I thought that impossible to store NetSuite code in Source Control. So technically form changes will never be reflected in version control because there may not be a source file associated with it. This is the part that really blows me away, how do shops with SOX deal with that huge problem?  I'll leave the question open for a day +1 or so to see if anyone else offers feedback.

Comment: Ah, yes there is currently no way to source control things like Form changes or Custom Records. NetSuite *does* offer SuiteBundles for that, but still not source control-able. NetSuite did announce that some form of an XML export was on the road map so that you could export things like custom fields, forms, and records to an XML file that could also be imported into another account. This XML could certainly be controlled, but again, for now it's just an item on their roadmap, nothing real.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't source control, but you can use SuiteBundler to copy items between accounts.  SuiteBundler allows you to choose from a lot of things like forms, scripts and custom records.  Later you can uninstall the bundle or dissolve it into the account.

Comment: Love to give credit where due. The SuiteBundler is a nice utility. I haven't been in NetSuite for a while- the move from typical client server applications proved difficult not to mention learning JavaScript and the NetSuite DOM/API at once at an older age.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so easy to explain in few words, here but: You can use a deployment account to get things work properly. So you continuosly work on dev accounts and use multiple bundle / bundle version for follow branches/Versions of customizations. You update bundle from dev to deploy account only when a version is stable and production envs always install / update bundle version from deploy (not from dev). Since bundles are versionable and infinite, you can use git + dev + deploy account for manage Cvs. For get a versionable version of a form just add &xml=t in url in any form. But this is read only